# Can I use the Android/Google speech recognition software on another platform?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, dictation

I have just acquired an Android phone recently... wonderful stuff. Starting to look at the OS guts and how to program the thing.

The voice-recognition-for-dictation is good too... given that this is an open-source OS, is there any way of harnessing the Android-Google speech recognition?  My current understanding is that the voice trace has to be sent to the Google servers to be processed, i.e. the software is not on the machine.  But I may be wrong!

Either way, does anybody have any idea whether such harnessing for one's own apps (on Android or another OS on a full-size 'puter, for example) is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about using voice recognition in your code somehow, then you can use it with the help of SpeechRecognizer class(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) and RecognizerIntent. 
But you can only use the currently existing functionality to some extent only. 
About the confusion as to whether it lies in device or not, try using your Voice Recognition after turning off internet on your phone. It wont work.

You can also look into API Demos for some example:
sdk\samples\android-10\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app\VoiceRecognition.java